# Problems with Facebook authentication

Tags: php, facebook

Okay, I hate facebook now. I've been fighting with this far too long.

I'm trying to use facebook as the login for my website, similar to what's done on stack overflow actually.

I've got my application setup and I've gone through step by step the Facebook guides but can't get anywhere.

I'm using the code examples from my app dashboard:

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxx',
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

This gives me a button, but as soon as I click the button it opens a new window and a blank page. any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/.
Generate the code for the button with the widget on that page.

I think you may be confusing the server-side usage of the API and the client-side usage. Decide which one you're going to need. If you're going to primarily use the API server-side, you can checkout the example they include in the facebook SDK package, it's pretty straightforward and should be enough to get you up and running.

Comment: I'll give that another go... I've gone through this restarting so many times it wouldn't surprise me if I'm getting confused. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't get the hang of it with the example let me know and I'll throw in a little script that handles a basic Facebook auth.